# I get css issues when i run react web application via the server

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My react application runs fine when I run it on local but when I try to run that via the production server ( Nginx ) or python server on local it gives the CSS issues.

npm version = 6.13.6
node version = v12.14.1

How can I fix it?

Here I'm providing the versions of various npm packages.

```
{
  "name": "Pmapper",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^1.10.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
}
```

Screenshot of local page 1
[image: local screenshot]

Screenshot of Page served from Server. 1
[image]

Screenshot of local Page 2.

[image]

Screenshot of Page served from Server 2. 
The same UI rendered from the server looks funky

[image]

For more visibility, if you click on the images, you can see them open on a separate tab.

Here's the full code located:  https://github.com/jpca999/mapper-Pkor

Comment: What are the css issues?

Comment: Please elaborate your issue, what CSS issue do you have

Comment: @AkhilAravind Can you figure the issue here ?

Comment: @AkhilAravind I've provided you with the full code link above.